# vscode - Open editor in default editor group

Tags: user-interface, visual-studio-code

I didn't found an option in vscode to define a default editor group. The goal is to have multiple editor groups but when I open a new file it opens always in the default one instead in the current selected editor group.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution is in this vscode issue: https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/124709#issuecomment-867413948

When this is done, you have the solution

Comment: Please see [How do I write a good answer?, Provide context for links](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer#:~:text=Provide%20context%20for%20links) where it notes "_Links to external resources are encouraged, but please add context around the link so your fellow users will have some idea what it is and why it’s there. Always quote the most relevant part of an important link, in case the external resource is unreachable or goes permanently offline. Links to other websites should always be helpful, but avoid making it necessary to click on them as much as possible._"